# Search for terms containing special characters in chat returns garbage

Tags: bug, chat, search, unicode

I did a search for A$, but a whole bunch of results containing "Å", "A's" and "as" were return, could not find one containing "A$":

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=A%24&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest

Same thing for other special characters such as "#".

Comment: As far as I could see, those characters are simply being ignored. See [this search](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ABC%24%22&user=&room=) vs. [this one](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ABC%22&user=&room=).

Comment: As a workaround until (if at all) this is fixed, use [Google insite search](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=site%3Achat.stackoverflow.com+%22A%24%22).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't think it's bug, right. If you search for things like "fixing", you'll find "fixed" too, etc. There's loads of annoying things in SE Chat Search (hence the many "SE Chat Search Is Broken") posts, but I'm not sure this one counts.

Comment: I get a feeling that chat bugs aren't that high in priority on the list of things, enhancements are even lower down the list.